# Why does double f96t12 fixture sometimes not light until a bulb is touched?

Tags: electrical

two f96t12 single pole bulbs in a grounded and properly wired metal fixture sometimes neither bulb will light until I touch one of them and both immediately light up.  If I touch a bulb and the metal fixture at the same time I feel a very light shock in my finger even when I am not grounded. I have seen this in other similar fixtures and always wondered about it.

Comment: Ratty old 1950s fluorescent tech that is starting to fail and is also ground-faulting.  Replace with modern electronic ballasts and while  you're at it, consider T8 type bulbs.  You'll love the light, and won't want to convert to LED at that point.

Comment: I would would say on the older 8’ lamps they are not “striking”  the lamps a or the ballast is worn out when you touch the lamp you distort the corona field that in not quite making it. I say this because only touching the glass and Glass being an insulator that is about all it can be and I have seen similar on 8’ lamps but don’t normally see this on 4’. A little more info and we could possibly narrow it down do you have a twist in starter with an old magnetic ballast, or a newer electronic ballast? How old are the lamps?

Comment: What do you have for a ballast in that fixture?